# Current in RC parallel circuit

Tags: analog, current-measurement

I have to compute the current in the resistor R1 and the current through the capacitor C1 at the circuit in the picture.

I thought to solve it like this:

1.Current in the resistor

I1=Vs/R= 3Vrms/ 100k ohm= 0.03 mA

2.Current through the capacitor:

I2=2*pi*f*C*Vs=2*pi*5.0kHz*1000pF*3 Vrms= 0.0942 mA

I am not sure if this is the right way to solve this problem, since I didn’t use the frequency when I calculated the current at the resistor.

[image]

Comment: Please rotate the image :)

Comment: Step 1 is wrong already. It assumes the voltage across the 100k resistor R1 is 3V, which it is not. It doesn't account for the voltage drop across Rs1

Comment: @Bart That was the wrong circuit, I put on the right circuit now. Maybe now it will make more sense. Thank you!

Comment: That is right, you don't need the frequency for calculating the resistor current, because its resistance is frequency independent and it is driven from a stiff voltage source, so there is the full voltage across the resistor. The same voltage is applied to the capacitor, so you can just multiply the voltage with its susceptance.